# Different Article Views for codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

how would I go about having different views for an article in Code Igniter.

For example I have one Index for all articles and I also have a view. But what If I want to have say 10 pictures for one article and only three for another?

So my view is:

```
<div id="wrapper">    
 <div id="main-wrapper" class="col-md-10 pull-right">
  <div id="main">   
   <div class="col-md-9">
    <div id="sec#" class="">
        <h2><?= $article['title']?></h2>
     <img border="0" src="<?= assetUrl() ?>img/article/<?= $article['image']?>">
     <h6>Date: <?= $article['date']?></h6>
     <h6>Author: <?= $article['author']?></h6>
     <br>
     <p><?= $article['body']?></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!--/right-->
 </div><!--Main wrapper--> 
</div><!--Wrapper-->
```

All the articles look the same. But what if I want to have pictures within the body of the article? And what if the number of pictures are different for each article.

I'm struggling with this, because all the articles look the same. And depending on the text, it would be nice to render pictures on different parts of the body.

Also, I've been adding HTML tags in the longtext and I save them in the database. Isn't this dangerous? I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this. But if I don't put any

tags, the body just displays as one big blob of text.

Comment: I think I would suggest a markdown editor for input and parse your articles with markdown when you output.   As to images, I think you might be overthinking it.  If the images are specific to the article, they should be included in the proper place in the body. The only exception would be an image for a header image (like you have above) which could live in a separate field in the database (as it appears it already is).  From what you've said, I don't think you need different views based on images in the body. Attach some CSS if you need to manipulate those images.

Comment: The problem is if that I add img tags in body I can't get the images to render because the <? tags for asset_url() get translated to %3C.